# Largest palindrome algorithm - JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've nearly solved this... It's Project Euler's [4th problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) and the answer is supposed to be 906609 but I keep getting 580085. I'd appreciate any help.

Code:

```
function largestPalin() {
  var a, b, c;

  for (a = 999; a > 100; a--) {
    for (b = a; b > 100; b--) {
      c = a * b;
      if (palinCheck(c)) {
         return c;
      }
    }
  }

  function palinCheck(c) {
    return c == c.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  }

}

console.log(largestPalin());
```

Comment: You are returning too early. You aren't guaranteeing you get the highest product, just that one of the 3-digit factors is largest (`995 x 583 < 993 x 913`).

Comment: You're first checking all values of `b`, for `a === 999`. Then for `a === 998`, etc. The first palindrome you find is at `a == 995, b == 583`. Basically, your method is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the first result you find, you should save it if it's larger than the last one you found and return it at the end.

```
var largestFound = 0;
for (a = 999; a > 100; a--) {
    for (b = a; b > 100; b--) {
        c = a * b;
        if (palinCheck(c)) {
            if (c > largestFound) {
                largestFound = c;
            }
        }
    }
}
return largestFound;
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! :) I would have thought that starting from 999 and looping down would return the larges number first though.